# jQuery event only if form successfully submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which has validation. At present it can take up to 10 seconds for the form to post. I would like to have a loading.gif load on form submit. The problem I have at the moment is the gif loads even if the form has not passed validation.

I need a way to get the gif to load ONLY if the form is valid, here is my current script:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#gif').css('visibility', 'visible');
    return true;
});
```

I am using parsley.js for validation

Comment: `passed validation` - which validation? Client-side? Server-side?

Comment: Client side, parlsey.js essentially just jazzes up adding the required tag to the form inputs

Comment: can you create a fiddle plz

Comment: A fiddle would have been good. Cause from what you have mentioned - it shouldn't work. What you are trying to achieve is the reverse of what you have mentioned. You want to show `GIF` until the for submits - cause once the form is submitted the page will be reloading (**if you are not using ajax**). So practically you are showing the `GIF` for the time it takes your `parlsey.js` to return result. So please share a fiddle! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.parsley().validate();

    if ($form.parsley().isValid())
       $('#gif').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Use parsley.js to determine whether the form is valid or not before showing the gif, by explicitly calling `validate`.

As an aside, be careful using `form` as a selector. You may have multiple forms per page. Use an id instead if possible.

Comment: Great thats it thanks, ill mark it correct when it lets me ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show/hide loading box until request is executing, you do not need to use default **form.action** attribute to post data. You need to do smth like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
   /* stop form from submitting normally */
   event.preventDefault();
   var $form = $(this);
   if(this.checkValidity()) { // form validation based on HTML 5 
       $('#gif').css('visibility', 'visible');
       /* Send the data using post */
       var posting = $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize());
       posting.done(function() {
          console.log("Request was executed successfully!!!")
       }).always(function() {
           // hide loading bar in any way on success/error
           $('#gif').css('visibility', 'hidden');
       })
   }
})
```